# Custom Wordpress Plugin: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, dom, datepicker

The library I'm using is called `hotel-datepicker`. After I successfully set up the plugin on my local machine in pure HTML & Javascript I got everything working. But after I implemented all functions into a custom WordPress plugin, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null at HotelDatepicker.init (hotel-datepicker.js?ver=5.1.3:196) at new HotelDatepicker (hotel-datepicker.js?ver=5.1.3:70) at main.js?ver=5.1.3:33 at main.js?ver=5.1.3:76
```

I already put the initialization of the `Hotel Datepicker` into a `document.ready` like function.

**Project URL**: http://alpensonne.printmedia-agentur.de/
**Hotel Datepicker**: https://github.com/benitolopez/hotel-datepicker

**Plugin it's main source code:**

```
function input_fields( $atts ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['gg'] ) ) {
        $post = array(
            'post_content' => $_POST['content'], 
            'post_title'   => $_POST['title']
        );
        $id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
    }
    ?> 
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4" id="datepicker__container">
                        <p>
                            » An- & Abreise
                            <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','alpensonne_load_js');

function alpensonne_load_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hotel-datepicker', plugins_url( '/js/hotel-datepicker.js', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', plugins_url( '/js/main.js', __FILE__ ));
}
```

**Plugin it's main javascript code:**

```
(function() {

  let datepicker = new HotelDatepicker(document.getElementById('datepicker'), options);

  ...

})();
```

I'm curious that the plugin works well locally, but as soon as it is called via WordPress, it doesn't find the `parentElement` anymore. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't in fact have it in a document.ready function, that's the issue - you're including main.js before the datepicker input is rendered on the page. If you move that line inside the jQuery document ready handler, then it should work:

```
(function() {

  $(function(){

    let datepicker = new HotelDatepicker(document.getElementById('datepicker'), options);

...
```

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I'm getting a "$ is not defined" error.

Comment: In that case, just replace $ with jQuery